# Android OpenGL es 2.0 error when modifying multiple objects on scene

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am having some problems with proper scene manipulations with `OpenGL ES 2.0`. On my screen I want to draw a rectangle and a cube. Rectangle should be moved to the bottom and scaled while cube should be moved to the top and scaled. What's more, I want to rotate this cube in all 3 axis.

This is what I've created so far:

```
@Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        float[] scratch = new float[16];
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -6, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(MVPMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0);

        Matrix.translateM(scratchMatrix1, 0, 0, -1.1f, 0);
        Matrix.scaleM(scratchMatrix3, 0, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(scratchMatrix2, 0, scratchMatrix1, 0, scratchMatrix3, 0);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch, 0, scratchMatrix2, 0, MVPMatrix, 0);
        rectangle.draw(scratch);

        Matrix.setRotateM(scratchMatrix1, 0, angleXVal, 1.0f, 0, 0);
        Matrix.setRotateM(rotationMatrix, 0, angleYVal, 0, 1.0f, 0);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(scratchMatrix2, 0, rotationMatrix, 0, scratchMatrix1, 0);
        Matrix.setRotateM(rotationMatrix, 0, angleZVal, 0, 0, 1.0f);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(scratchMatrix3, 0, rotationMatrix, 0, scratchMatrix2, 0);

        Matrix.translateM(scratchMatrix1, 0, 0, 0.3f, 0);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(scratchMatrix2, 0, scratchMatrix3, 0, scratchMatrix1, 0);
        Matrix.scaleM(scratchMatrix1, 0, 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(scratchMatrix3, 0, scratchMatrix2, 0, scratchMatrix1, 0);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch, 0, scratchMatrix2, 0, MVPMatrix, 0);

        cube.draw(scratch);
    }
```

The problem is that when I am rotating the cube also the rectangle is moving. It is this same with scale and translating of cube - it is pulling the rectangle.

For me it looks like the matrices are connected somewhere but I don't see where, because the rectangle is drawn first and scratch matrix is overwritten later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that is your complete `onDrawFrame()` code, `scratchMatrix1` etc are class member variables that persist from frame to frame.

That means that translations from one frame will carry over to the next, because [Matrix.translateM()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/Matrix.html#translateM(float[],%20int,%20float,%20float,%20float)) applies a translation to an existing matrix transform by adding to it, rather than setting the matrix to a given translation matrix and overwriting the previous values. So the translations will accumulate over several frames.

That means that when you translate the cube, the translation will still be sitting in `scratchMatrix1` the next time `onDrawFrame` is called, and the rectangle translation will be added to it rather than be set afresh.

The same goes for [Matrix.scaleM()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/Matrix.html#scaleM(float[],%20int,%20float,%20float,%20float)).

You can rectify this by initializing all the scratch matrices to identity at the start of the function, and again before beginning the calculation of the cube transform matrix:

```
 Matrix.setIdentityM(scratchMatrix1, 0);
 Matrix.setIdentityM(scratchMatrix2, 0);
 Matrix.setIdentityM(scratchMatrix3, 0);
 Matrix.setIdentityM(scratch, 0);
```

Comment: I didn't know that it is only adding not overwriting it. So only `Matrix.rotateM()` is overwriting here?

Comment: multiplyMM and rotateM are overwriting. translateM and scaleM are applied to the current values.